# CSS RWD with uneven boxes

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have six uneven boxes, each has margin of 50px and they lined up to three columns. Is it better to use flexbox or grid of these kinds of problem? and How to change them from three columns to two columns (responsive) when view width is 630px while keep the same order(ex, box 1 to 6)?

code sample : ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-wiles-7kb4wc?file=/src/App.js))

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: @Cédric yes, https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-wiles-7kb4wc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

You will probably get more control of layout using grid rather than flex.

With grid you can specify which column an item is to go in. You can also specify that the system is to use the first available cell to put an item in (using 'dense') so the grid can be filled up even though you are putting the first item into the third cell.

This snippet uses the code you have given but as pure HTML/CSS.

It has a media query at 600px which of course can be altered as required. At that point it sets the grid to have 2 columns instead of 3.

The 50px requirement is met by using gap.

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.App>* {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}

.App> :nth-child(3n+1) {
  transform: translateY(10px);
  grid-column: 3;
}

.App> :nth-child(3n+2) {
  transform: translateY(30px);
  grid-column: 2;
}

.App> :nth-child(3n) {
  transform: translateY(50px);
  grid-column: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .App {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .App> :nth-child(odd) {
    grid-column: 2;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  .App> :nth-child(even) {
    grid-column: 1;
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div style="background-color: green;">box1</div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow;">box2</div>
  <div style="background-color: orange;">box3</div>
  <div style="background-color: purple;">box4</div>
  <div style="background-color: blue;">box5</div>
  <div style="background-color: grey;">box6</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">box7</div>
  <div style="background-color: brown;">box8</div>
</div>
```